# How to query all of something using $resource in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, jax-rs

I'm not convinced that I understand how to properly use Angular's services.  I'm using a JAX-RS server-side.

If services are supposed to work like (as taken from the [phonecat example](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/js/services.js))...

```
angular.module('workstation.services', ['ngResource']).
    factory('WorkflowService', function($resource, apiUrl){
        return $resource(apiUrl+'/api/workflow/:uuid', {uuid:'@uuid'}, {});
    });
```

Then how do I query for all workflows?  I can't use the `WorkflowService` to accomplish that because it's already tried to `/api/workflow/:uuid`.  I would need to have another service which is based around another URL.

This doesn't seem like it's very flexible, unless I'm using it wrong.

I'm used to seeing a `Service` handle all querying for data and have methods like `WorkflowService.getActiveWorkflows()` to return `Workflow[]`

However I'm not sure how to organize this service because I still want to have methods that interact with a single entity, like `WorkflowService.save(workflow);`.  With how `$resource`s are designed to be around a specific RESTful URL it's tough to structure that correctly...

Comment: If you call the method without passing the :uuid parameter, Angular will remove this parameter from your url, as I know. Did you try to call the service like here: https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js

Comment: +1 for descriptive title (all of something) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution...

This allows me to build whatever solutions I want in the service, while still having access to the resource available.

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

angular.module('workstation.services', ['ngResource']).
    service('WorkflowService', function ($resource, $http, apiUrl) {
        var service = new BaseService($resource(apiUrl+'/api/workflow/:uuid', {uuid:'@uuid'}, {}));

        /* Get all available workflows */
        service.getWorkflows = function () {
            return $http.get(apiUrl+'/api/workflow/getAllActive').then(function (response) { return response.data });
        }

        return service;
    });

/* Base service */
function BaseService(resource) {
    this.resource = resource
};
BaseService.prototype.getResource = function () { return this.resource }
BaseService.prototype.newResourceInstance = function () { return new this.resource }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [angular documentation from $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), read the *actions* arguments. It supports to define a url that will override the base url for a specific action.

Using a default action 'queryAll' you can query *all of something* from a resource.

Example:

```
angular.module('workstation.services', ['ngResource']).
factory('WorkflowService', function($resource, apiUrl){
    return $resource(apiUrl+'/api/workflow/:uuid', {uuid:'@uuid'}, {
        queryAll: {
            url: apiUrl + '/api/workflow/getAllActive',
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            isArray: true
        }
    });
});
```